# wxWidgets: Properly making a user control that contains other controls inside itself

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm trying to make a user control in wxWidgets to represent a channel in an audio mixer. So, each channel has a standard set of controls inside itself (some sliders, buttons, etc..).

So inside my class I have a sizer in which I add the various child controls I need. So far that works.

But the problems I have are

- if I derive from wxPanel, the layout of the control works as I expect it (it gets expanded in the sizer to fit the child controls), however none of the children get any events (like EVT_LEFT_DOWN etc). I tried connecting an event for the main control that runs event.Skip() but that didn't help.
- If I change my class to derive from wxControl instead (or wxFrame, or possibly a number of others I tried), the child controls *do* get events, but the whole thing doesn't get expanded in the sizer it's located in, it just gets drawn as a tiny box (some 10-20 square px) even though the child controls take up much more space.

Any ideas?

*Update:*

**mangoMixerStrip.cpp**

```
mangoMixerStrip::mangoMixerStrip(wxFrame* parent, HostChannel* channel) : wxPanel(parent)
{
    myChannel = channel;
    SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(172,81,90));

    wxBoxSizer* s = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

    // some custom controls i made which all work fine when added like any other control, derived from wxPanel also
    faderPan = new mangoFader(parent, 200, false, 55);
    faderGain = new mangoFader(parent, 200, true, 126);    
    buttonSolo = new mangoButton(parent, false, ButtonGraphic::Solo);

    s->Add(faderPan);
    s->Add(buttonSolo);
    s->Add(faderGain);

    this->SetSizer(s);

    this->Connect(wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN, wxMouseEventHandler(mangoMixerStrip::mouseDown)); // this function simply contains event.Skip()
}
```

**in my main wxFrame**

```
mangoFrameMain::mangoFrameMain(wxWindow* parent) : FrameMain( parent )
{   
    HostChannel* h =  new HostChannel();
    h->setName("what up"); // these 2 lines unrelated to the UI

    mangoMixerStrip *test = new mangoMixerStrip(this, h);
    this->GetSizer()->Add(test, 1, wxFIXED_MINSIZE, 0);
}
```

And to clarify: the mangoMixerStrip instance itself gets any events I connect to it, but its child controls do not.

Comment: Deriving from wxPanel is the correct way to go.  It is strange that your controls are not getting events.  Please post your code so we can see what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controls should be children of your class derived from wxPanel, NOT children of the panel's parent.

```
   faderPan = new mangoFader(parent, 200, false, 55);
```

should be

```
  faderPan = new mangoFader(this, 200, false, 55);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a wxFrame, you can also do so. However you must make sure that once you create your frame, you add a sizer to the frame and then a panel, and then another sizer. Then you can put whatever you want within the sizer. For some reason wxwidgets will not size right if you do not place the sizer, then panel, then sizer.

Comment: Wow!  That sounds like a complicated way to do what should be simple!